# PaperJS fill a raster with a color without iiterating over the pixels

Tags: javascript, paperjs

In PaperJS is it possible to fill a raster with a color without iterating over each pixel?

So say you have a PNG with some transparency, the pixels with no transparency will have a different color.

AFAIK you can iterate over each pixel http://paperjs.org/tutorials/images/using-pixel-colors/ and do it manually (creating an alternate pixel for each image pixel), but ideally there is a solution that doesn't require doing this pixel by pixel.

It would be nice to use the raster as a clipping mask to show the color beneath it but I believe that only works with paths.

Grateful for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative can be to make a clever usage of blend mode.
The principle is to use the raster as an alpha source for a shape that is positioned over it.
I don't have much time to elaborate right now, now but here is a [sketch](http://sketch.paperjs.org/#V/0.12.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) that should get you on the track.

```js
const url = 'data:image/png;base64,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';
const raster = new paper.Raster(url);
raster.blendMode = 'destination-in';
raster.onLoad = () => {
    const rectangle = new Path.Rectangle({
        rectangle: raster.bounds,
        fillColor: 'orange'
    });
    new Group([rectangle, raster]);
    project.activeLayer.fitBounds(view.bounds.scale(0.8));
};
```

The next challenge is to scope this effect so that the blending doesn't affect the other shapes of the scene. On this topic, I posted some advanced example in Paper.js repo, you should be able to find them.

Comment: This is essentially what I did, I had to add a `"blendMode": "source-over"` on the surrounding group to stop it bleeding over but seems to work without a hitch.